# ReactTransitionGroup code explanation

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I am trying to get my head around the code in ReactTransitionGroup and I am confused as to Why performEnter is called in [componentDidUpdate](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/81d4d7bf242bba3b5e10ff12d224d49dac181f35/src/addons/transitions/ReactTransitionGroup.js#L94) and not componentDidMount.  My understanding of componentDidUpdate is that it is called after render and when the state has altered.

So I'm confused as to why it is called here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`performEnter` animates the child, and children are animated in and out when they appear in or disappear from the parent component on *subsequent* renders—they're not animated if they're already contained in the parent upon the first render.